# Suppress PowerShell Warning

Tags: 2013, powershell

How can I get rid of these warning? If these warning cannot be eliminated how can I suppress them?

For instance, the warnings happen at this line:

```
$sourceWebSite = Get-SPWeb -Limit All -Identity "SomeSite" -EA 0
$sourceLibrary = $sourceWebSite.Lists["Record Library"] 
$sourceView = $sourceLibrary.Views["Credentialing"]
```

[image]

Comment: try this one "-WarningPreference SilentlyContinue" instead of -EA 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try by adding WarningAction:SilentlyContinue in the first line

Comment: thanks that did it: $sourceWebSite = Get-SPWeb -Limit All -Identity "SomeSite" -EA 0 -WA 0

Comment: Just a tip, you may want to leave ErrorAction alone, (remove -EA 0) in case you get an unexpected error.

Comment: Note that the correct format would be `$WarningAction = 'SilentlyContinue'` if you wanted to do it on another line.